# How do I show that a continuous variable is a predictor of categorical variable that takes the value of 1 or 0 using R

Tags: r, logistic, categorical-data

I want to perform a test to see if the continuous variable is a predictor of the categorical variable. 
More information: I was given identifier IDs with corresponding dichotomous values (Call it CD, takes a value either 0 or 1). Another file contained the same IDs with corresponding continuous values (call it PS). I was able to match the values of the two variables using the IDs. Now I'm stuck on how to show that PS is a good predictor of CD.

![Data]: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKT29.jpg)

Comment: You want to predict a binary dependent variable using a continuous independent variable? [tag:logistic] regression is probably your first choice. Try to give more details, if you want a more specific answer. Maybe look at [asking questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/asking) and [good questions](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1483/27276).

Comment: I was able to edit my question to make it more in detail.

Comment: Questions that are only about software (e.g. error messages, code or packages, etc.)
are generally off topic here. If you have a substantive machine learning or
statistical question, please edit to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You already tagged your post with the logistic regression tag. That is precisely the answer. Observations with missing predictors do get dropped from the analysis. Is there something else you need clarification on?

Edit: The UCLA website has [a good guide](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/) to logistic regression in R. Your screenshot looks like the data display from RStudio. The UCLA website also has guides for SAS and Stata.

Comment: I just edited the question, I'm not entirely sure on how to carry out the logistic regression.

Comment: @Qass see my edit for a link.